# How to classify White-box/black-box, systematic selection and random selection of test case strategies

Tags: testing

While writing my thesis, I am facing the problem of how to classify the testing strategies.
Following section 1.5 of this [thesis](https://researchbank.swinburne.edu.au/file/368a27be-7d18-415f-b88a-b32ae9f87b7e/1/Fei-Ching%20Kuo%20Thesis.pdf):
If black-box and white-box are test case selection methodologies to solve the reliable test case set problem, then where to put random/systematic test case selection strategies ?

Initially, I thought random/systematic test case selection strategies will come under the black-box testing because random testing and partition testing are the sub-categories of black-box testing.

Then, the problem is, even in white-box testing, we often do the partitioning of input domain to make homogeneous partitions. For example, in unit testing, we select representative test case that represents a partition of input domain.

Now, I have done this classification:
Software testing methodology will have two components
component 1. Test case design strategies (black-box & white-box)
component 2. test case selection strategies (random & systematic selection of test cases)

Any help in this?

Comment: I doubt the four terms in stake have a definition out of any context to make this question answerable without reading the parts of the thesis you linked to. Scanning through the thesis, it seems it provides the necessary context. Unfortunately, questions which are not meaningful without the information from an external link, are usually not welcome by our community. Links tend to rot, so making the Q&A useless after some while. I would recommend you cite enough of the definitions for the four terms from the thesis to make this question answerable ...

Comment: ... however, I would not be astonished if you go this route, you can answer your own question afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd agree with your assessment. Black-box and white-box describe methods to create test cases, not select from existing test cases. Systematic and random testing describe methods to choose existing test cases for execution. However, I can see cases where attempting to review sets of test cases for systematic execution or placing into a pool for random selection may reveal the need for new test cases, which could be created using black-box or white-box testing techniques.

Black-box and white-box are ways to classify what you know when you create the test cases. In black-box test cases, you often have a description of what the component under test is supposed to do and the interface (whether it's an API or a user interface) and create the test cases based only on this information. When you are performing white-box testing, you can look at all of the implementation details that you want to in order to help find new or interesting cases for both functional or non-functional concerns.

The selection of test cases is a different concern. Once you have test cases, you may end up in situations where you cannot run the full suite of cases that are interesting. You may choose to choose the scope of testing based on knowledge of what you're testing and the changes or you may find the set of test cases that provide coverage for the area of concern and randomly select.

The thesis is quite long, at over 150 pages, so I haven't read the whole thing, but the terms don't seem to be used in the same way that I've seen them used in industry. I'm not sure if this is a disconnect between academia and industry or if there are some less common uses in industry that more closely align with how the thesis author uses them.

Comment: Only the first chapter, especially section 1.5 was needed to be studied where the author describes two different discrete approaches for test case selection: 1) black-box/white-box 2) systematic/random selection. I believe, this is incorrect because I think these approaches are interconnected with each other. Even the author says: random testing is a black box testing technique. Also, says: we can select test cases in systematic way and random way.

Comment: @MuhammadAshfaq I don't think the assertion that random testing is a black-box testing technique is correct. They can't be compared - one is a method of selecting test cases or test paths and the other is a method of creating test cases. The text uses terms in a way that I've never seen before in any text I've read or discussion I've had.

Comment: I fully agree with your answer. So, would you please like to cite some of the text that you have read so that I read that too and cite it in my thesis. This will help us to provide some evidence based on literature.

Comment: @MuhammadAshfaq I'm afraid I can't do that. Most of it comes from conversations with other people. Some of the other sources are things I've read over the past 10 years or so, and include books, blogs, podcasts, and more.

Comment: Then stopping coverage criteria i.e. code coverage, branch coverage etc. will be attributed to White-box testing or systematic testing or when systematic testing used with white-box testing?

Comment: @MuhammadAshfaq That question makes no sense. You can measure coverage in both white-box and black-box testing. If the tester can see the actual lines of code under test, it becomes white box. But a tool or another person can deliver information about coverage to the tester without revealing the code under test. Systematic testing is just a method of choosing test cases and you can use coverage rules to determine if you've chosen enough test cases.